# How can I divert audio from jack to USB port? 

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, conversion, dell-inspiron

I have a problem with the fact that my Dell Laptop has the jack audio output uncomfortably to the front, and I always bump the jack with my knee. Is there any possibility to divert the audio stream (regardless if it streams from winamp, VLC, media players or browsers) to any of the USB ports situated on the sides? 
If possible I`ll then buy a USB to jack converter, in which I will plug the above mentioned problematic jack.

Windows 7, Dell Inspiron 1525.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you have been looking at things like these...
[Logitech](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058P0I2C) [Syba](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) etc...
Those are not "USB to jack converters", they are USB sound cards.  You need to install software with them, and then you have the laptop stop using the sound card that originally came with it, in favor of the new USB sound card you just installed.

No, you cannot just find some converter, and then "redirect" the audio output to a USB port.  The computer is not built to work that way... the onboard sound card doesn't work that way for it is not wired that way.

So... your idea of using a USB sound card will work, just not how you thought it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought a Logitech H800 headset (USB/Bluetooth) and Windows just automatically routed my audio to the headset.  It works this way on my work computer, my home computer, my Toshiba personal laptop, and my Dell Latitude E6500.

I don't know if an adapter will behave the same way, but a USB headset may be a viable alternative for you.

Comment: USB powered/connected speakers will behave the same way.